# Unable to connect WiFi in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I am using Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop and I'm not able to connect to a Wifi device nor to a Bluetooth device. Earlier I did not faced this kind of problem. But now its there. Anyone please guide me.

Comment: Try with these [answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx/).

Comment: Please indicate which card your laptop has by posting the output of `lspci -vnn | grep Network`.

Answer (score 2):

Classic problem, For your OS to understand what to do with your hardware you need something called a driver. it is a peice of software that tells your computer what to do with your hardware (wifi drivers, bluetooth you name it) they cant include it all by default so what you're gonna have to do is,

1. Plug your laptop into your Ethernet cable.
2. Go open terminal and type `sudo apt-get install jockey`
3. Put in your password (You wont see the password your typing for security reasons)
4. run it, download all the drivers it asks you too.

Reboot

This should work for you, but if jockey didnt detect anything then go to
wirless.kernal.org and look around there try **jockey** first, its easier. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible that you are referring to the **jockey** package?