# Help, no wireless for laptop hp pavilion notebook PC 15-n013sq

Tags: wireless, networking, hp-pavilion

I can't use wireless on my laptop , i have no wireless network on the right upper corner.
I have read some post but i don't understand what to do at all , because I'm a new user to Ubuntu (version 12.04.3 LTS )

Can anyone guide me to  fix this issue please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered the other guys question and my answer will be just as relevant here
[Unable to connect WiFi in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411769/unable-to-connect-wifi-in-ubuntu-12-04/411778#411778)

> Classic problem, For your OS to understand what to do with your
>   hardware you need something called a driver. it is a peice of software
>   that tells your computer what to do with your hardware (wifi drivers,
>   bluetooth you name it) they cant include it all by default so what
>   you're gonna have to do is,
>
> Plug your laptop into your Ethernet cable. Go open terminal and type
>   sudo apt-get install jockey Put in your password (You wont see the
>   password your typing for security reasons) run it, download all the
>   drivers it asks you too. Reboot
>
> This should work for you, but if jockey didnt detect anything then go
>   to wirless.kernal.org and look around there try jockey first, its
>   easier. Hope this helps.